# Mysql select count where count > 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select items which have nbre > 0 in this query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.nom, c.photo,
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM touist_materiel 
     WHERE cat=c.id AND marque=7 AND actif=1
    ) as nbre
FROM touist_materiel_cat c
INNER JOIN touist_materiel m ON m.cat=c.id 
WHERE nbre > 0 
GROUP BY m.cat 
ORDER BY c.nom
```

This query doesn't work, how can I have the "where nbre > 0" working?
Thanks

Comment: It is not easy to understand what you're trying to have. Can you make a sqlfiddle and explain exactly what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try without subquery?

```
SELECT c.id, c.nom, c.photo, count(m.*) AS nbre
FROM touist_materiel_cat c
INNER JOIN touist_materiel m
  ON m.cat=c.id AND m.marque=7 AND m.actif=1
GROUP BY m.cat
ORDER BY c.nom
```

With INNER JOIN, we always have count(m.*) > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tmc.id, tmc.nom, tmc.photo, count(tm.*) AS nbre
  FROM touist_materiel_cat tmc
  INNER JOIN touist_materiel tm
    ON tm.cat=tmc.id 
  WHERE nbre > 0 
    AND tm.marque=7 
    AND tm.actif=1
  GROUP BY tm.cat 
  ORDER BY tmc.nom;
```